# :GoInstallBinaries is ok but vim-go is not working

Tags: go, vim, vim-go

I am installing fatih/vim-go plugin. After install (I am using Vim8 packages) I run `:GoInstallBinaries`. In the image installation is complete.

[image]

So, ... why if I run command such `GoRun` the editor answer me with:

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/issues

Comment: Get the runtime logs, and check for errors in there. As it stands, there's no where near enough information to determine what's wrong. To get some logs, run `vim -V9go_run.log main.go`, and then run `:GoRun`